# search without subdivision in sql

Tags: mysql

Search the value without subdivisions.

I have jobref column and it looks like

```
1.abc
2.abc_1
3.abc_2
4.abc_3
5.abc_3_1
6.abc_3_2
7.abc_3_3
8.abc_2_1
9.abc_2_2
```

Now my question is

1. If I search the `jobref` column using 'abc' it shows me `abc_1,abc_2,abc_3` and I dont want to display the subdivisions .
2. If I search using 'abc_3' now it want to show only the subdivision part starting with '`abc_3,abc_3_1,...,abc_3_3`'. How to do that in MySQL?

Comment: remove the % wildcard from your search query. Oh btw, can you please reformulate your question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,this is my query "select jobref from xxx where uid = 'yy' and jobref like 'abc%' order by jobref desc limit 1". it shows the result as 'abc_3_3'. but what i actually want is 'abc_3'. if i search abc_3 that time it used to show 'abc_3_3' how to do that

Comment: maybe time to look at the different wildcard operators mysql offers: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html